# I need a book to continue experimenting with ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, books

I am a CS student who finished his third year in school, and I'm interested in game development. This summer, I bought a book named "Foundation Game Design with Flash" by Rex Van Der Spuy. I'm halfway through it. It's a book for beginners, but it still helped me get familiar with Flash interface and AS3 syntax.

After I finish this book, I want to continue learning. I'm going to buy another book soon, and currently I'm considering three different items: [Real-World Flash Game Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240817680), [AdvancED Game Design with Flash](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430227397) and "Foundation ActionScript 3.0 Animation: Making Things Move!" I want an intermediate level book. I now understand basic concepts of Flash and AS3, and can google my way through if I can't understand a concept in the book I'm going to buy.

Do any of you have a suggestion among these three? I only have budget for one. If you think I can benefit more from a completely different book, that's also good advice. Keep in mind that I will keep buying books as I finish them, so you can suggest an order of books to follow, aswell.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6874/looking-for-a-good-actionscript-3-book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only read **Foundation ActionScript 3.0 Animation: Making Things Move!** by Keith Peters but it was a good read, covered some interesting topics and the code was good. The author also runs the blog http://www.bit-101.com/blog/. He has also written another book **AdvancED ActionScript 3.0 Animation** which is similar to the first, but with different topics, although I would read his first one to begin with.

Comment: +1 on Foundation ActionScript 3.0 Animation - If you're interested in flash game programming, that book has so many useful and fun to play with bits of code that will definitelly keep you entertained. The follow up book (Advanced Actionscript Animation is also good)

Comment: since no one else gave any other suggestions, and since i chose the book you mentioned to buy, i accept this answer. :) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The book i used for AS3 was ActionScript 3.0 Game Programming University.
Everything is explained very well, and it was fun working with the book.

Its completely based on games tho.